# Visual Studio Edit and Continue / ASP.NET Development Server / Detach / Attach

Tags: asp.net, edit, continue

I find the Edit & Continue feature is a great advantage if you develop an ASP.NET project. The only "problem" I run into is that if I want to use Edit & Continue, I need to start the debugger and run the code in the ASP.NET Development Server. When I want to stop debugging for a moment, the server stops and the web app is not available anymore -> Logic.

I would like to be able to start the server with the Edit & Continue feature, but not attach the debugger to the process yet. After some actions (login, filling a form etc), I want to attach the debugger to the process and be able to break at breakpoints and use the Edit & Continue feature.

It does work to start the server without debugging mode and as soon as I attach to the development server process, it does break, but by that time, the Edit & Continue does not work anymore. It tells me:

```
Changes are not allowed in the following cases:
 - When the degbugger has been attached to an already running process.
 - The code being debugged was optimized at build or run time.
 - The assembly being debugged is loaded as domain-neutral.
 - The assembly being debugged was loaded through reflection.
 - When Intellitrace events and call information is enabled."
```

Is there a way to attach later and have a working Edit & Continue?

Why do I want this:
Imagine that I have a lot of breakpoints in my code and don't want to disable them one by one, but I would like to attach to the server process only after I have made some actions (login, filling out a form etc), in order to prevent that I need to continue on each break. Once I am just before my action I need to debug, I want to attach and then be able to edit the code without the need of restarting the web server and doing all the actions all over again.

I hope I was clear enough...

Comment: It seams that this is not possible? Am I the only one who bothers this fact, that you need to remove / disable the breakpoints and re-enable, which takes a certain time if you have set a lot of them?